# How do you create an object containing an array using literals

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I want to do this using literals:

```
newObject.object[0].time = 1200;
```

But the following code gives an error:

```
var newObject = {
    object[0].time: 1200
};
```

Is there any way to construct such an objects using literals?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var newObject = {        // base object
    object: [            // array as "newObject.object"
        {                // object as a first element of array
            time: 1200
        }
    ]
};

console.log(newObject.object[0].time);  // 1200
```